# How to Post with Application Name

Tags: facebook, authentication

I'm using the simple code to post on user's wall. This:

```
$postwall = $facebook->api("/".$id."/feed", 'post', array(

                    'message' => "test",
                    'link'    => 'http://www.Google.com',
                    'name'    => 'test.',
                    'description'=> 'test.'
                    ));
```

This code works but, it's posting with mine facebook name. I want to post with the application name. I searched for authenticating with application name, i tried everything but finally i didn't resolve my problem. Is there anyone who can help me with this please ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible. I guess this is the error you'll get:

> (#200) Posts where the actor is a page
>   cannot also include a target_id

What I've done here is that getting the `manage_pages` permission and then get the application (profile page) `access_token` and tried to append it to the POST call.