# FB Graph API: Posting as a page, to a different page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using Facebook's Javascript SDK, and I need a way to let users post to a specific page impersonating one of the pages they own. Posting as the user works perfectly, but I can seem to get this right:

```
var data = {
    access_token: access,
    message: "Hello"
};

FB.api("/" + page_id + "/feed", "post", data, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

**page_id** is the numeric ID of the specific page I want to post to, and **access** is the access_token retrieved from the "me/accounts" api, using the manage_pages authorization.

The output I recieve from the response variable is the following object:

```
error: Object
    code: 200
    message: "(#200) Posts where the actor is a page cannot also include a target_id"
    type: "OAuthException"
```

I couldn't find the answer to this anywhere. Is this just not possible? It can't be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quick googling suggests it's not possible:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706873/post-on-wall-fan-page-to-a-fan-page-that-likes

[How to Post with Application Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634151/how-to-post-with-application-name)

also, take a look at the old REST API documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/

> target_id
>
> Note: If you specify a Page ID as the uid, you cannot specify a
> target_id. Pages cannot write on other users' Walls.
>
> Note: You cannot publish to an application profile page's Wall.